# Configuring Threadpool Max Threads via app.config?

Tags: c#, .net

Can I configure the max threads via the config file?

Answer (score 6):

No - However, this can be set based on configuration values you read, by calling [ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads.aspx).

Comment: I had a feeling that was the case since I couldn't find anything on the web.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not directly. But you could read the desired value of maximum number of threads in the thread pool from a config file and pass the values to [`ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads.aspx).

But if you need to change the number of threads in the thread pool you should seriously consider rearchitecting your application.

Note, in particular:

> Setting the thread pool size too large can cause performance problems. If too many threads are executing at the same time, the task switching overhead becomes a significant factor.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite "the" config file, but these days you can set the threadpool worker maximum using `runtimeconfig.json`:

```
{
   "runtimeOptions": {
      "configProperties": {
         "System.Threading.ThreadPool.MaxThreads": 20
      }
   }
}
```

I have not tried this myself (yet).

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/core/runtime-config/threading#maximum-threads