# How to change CLR thread-pool configurations?

Tags: configuration, clr, threadpool

I was reading about thread-pool configurations for asp.net applications in `machine.config`. Author mentioned this is about asp.net thread-pool and not about `CLR` thread-pool.

How we can change `CLR` thread-pool configurations ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SetMaxThreads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads.aspx) to define the size of the pool. According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338876/configuring-threadpool-max-threads-via-app-config), there is no declarative way to set it.

Comment: This is good for run-time. How can I change it permanently (via a config file I mean). Thanks

Comment: See my answer. By declarative way, I mean XML configuration. Follow the link.