# .NET ThreadPool and Configuration

Tags: .net, multithreading, threadpool

First question, is the ThreadPool configuration on process level? if i change the threadpool configuration in one process does it affect the other .NET processes?

Second question, if i want to have multiple ThreadPools (one threadpools with 5 threads in one component of the application and one threadpool with 2 threads in another component ) how to configure them or what to use as an alternative?

Thanks for helping

Comment: "There is one thread pool per process": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx. I doubt very seriously that you need separate pools per component. What is your use case?

Comment: I don't have a specific case, just was wondering if that was a correct way of thinking about ThreadPools, however i think that you are correct, i should be fine with one thread pool 99% of the time. If i need more control i can spawn threads manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have noticed you cannot change the `ThreadPool` configuration from a global machine configuration file (machine.config) or an application level configuration file (app.config or web.config for ASP.NET apps).

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338876/configuring-threadpool-max-threads-via-app-config) you can do it by code, eventually reading the settings from a config file manually.

This implies that changes done in this way at runtime are limited to your application, surely do not span across other running processes on same server or machine.

Comment: You can set min/max for both the standard thread pool and the IO thread pool from the global configuration (machine.config). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7w2sway1(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @Arical - that settings only applies to ASP.NET, not to any .NET process. eg, it would have no effect on a console program or a Windows service.